# How do I add a blank line in an unix man page using groff?

Tags: manpage, groff

I tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
.SH ADD A NEW TEST
Everytime you invoke a command within the shell,
this is what actually happens: the shell search for a folder
named as your command inside the directory
.B path/to/framework/Tests
or any subfolder,
if it finds such a folder, it will search for a file called
main.pl and will launch it.
.br
.br
Adding a new test is easy as create a new folder, put a main.pl
file inside it and invoke the folder name. Of course, for a better
integration with the whole system you should follow
some guide lines. Invoke the command
.B skeleton
to find out where the skeleton file is installed in your
system. Have a look to that file. It's well commented and
cover all possibile case and scenarios. Use it as a model to write
your own test.
```

The second `.br` is simply ignored.

Comment: nroff has the concept of *paragraphs*, not *empty lines*. A new paragraph is started simply by entering an empty line, *but* that does *not* mean that an empty line is added between paragraphs on output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish it by using `.PP` when a paragraph begins.

```
.SH ADD A NEW TEST
.PP
Everytime you invoke a command within the shell,
this is what actually happens: the shell search for a folder
named as your command inside the directory
.B path/to/framework/Tests
or any subfolder,
if it finds such a folder, it will search for a file called
main.pl and will launch it.
.PP
Adding a new test is easy as create a new folder, put a main.pl
file inside it and invoke the folder name. Of course, for a better
integration with the whole system you should follow
some guide lines. Invoke the command
.B skeleton
to find out where the skeleton file is installed in your
system. Have a look to that file. It's well commented and
cover all possibile case and scenarios. Use it as a model to write
your own test.
```

Comment: `.PP` or `.LP` start a new paragraph, but `.sp n` adds a vertical space of *n* lines. Unsure what you want and why you want it.